# Pygame Jumper collision detection not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game similar to what is seen in google chrome when the internet is down for my A Level computer science course work. I have run into an issue regarding collision detection and any help would be greatly appreciated.

When i try to declare more than one platform to stop player movement (collision detection) all platforms stop stopping player movement. But when i have only one platform stopping player movement it will work.

All of my code is located here: https://github.com/VincenzoLaRoche/ComputerScienceCourseWork

Comment: Most people on here aren't going to take the time to look through all of your code just to find your bug.  You will have better luck getting an answer if you can reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: Just for your information: This is __horrible__ code design. I hope you will refactor it in the future.

Comment: I second @MegaIng 's statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your are handling the platforms completely separate. So if you stand on one, you are not touching the other one so it makes you fall. For this to stop, you have to modify the t1o player methods `collision_detect` and `do` like so:

```
def collision_detect(self, platform):
    if self.x > platform.x and self.x < platform.x2:
        if self.y + 40 == platform.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def do(self):
    self.keys()
    self.move()
    self.draw()
    c1 = self.collision_detect(platform(0, 500, 800, 10))
    c2 = self.collision_detect(platform(0, 480, 400, 10))
    if c1 or c2:
        self.yVel = 0
        Constants.CANJUMP = True
    else:
        self.yVel = 5
        Constants.CANJUMP = False
```